# How to sort a 2d array based on these conditions ? (The conditions are given within the code)

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, vector, bubble-sort

```
/*
 The program must accept N integers as the input.  Each integer is
 given a weight.  The program must sort the integers in ascending
 order based on their weight and print the integers along with their
 weights as the output as given in the Example Input/Output
 sections.  The weight of each integer is calculated based on the
 conditions given below.


Conditions:
Weight = 5 if it is a perfect cube.
Weight = 4 if it is a multiple of 4 and divisible by 6.
Weight = 3 if it is a prime number.

Hint: Use stable sort (insertion sort, bubble sort or merge sort).

Boundary Conditions:
1 <= N <= 1000

Input Format:
The first line contains N.
The second line contains N integers separated by a space.

Output Format:
The first line contains integers with their weight as given in the Example Input/Output sections.

Example Input/Output 1:
Input:
7
10 36 54 89 12 216 27

Output:
<10,0>,<54,0>,<89,3>,<36,4>,<12,4>,<27,5>,<216,9>

Example Input/Output 2:
Input:
10
12 18 16 64 14 30 37 27 343 216

Output:
<18,0>,<16,0>,<14,0>,<30,0>,<37,3>,<12,4>,<64,5>,<27,5>,<343,5>,<216,9>
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int perfcube(int n)
{
    int cubert = cbrt(n);
    if (cubert * cubert * cubert == n)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

int divis(int n)
{
    if (n % 4 == 0 && n % 6 == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int prime(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count == 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int a[n];
    int b[n][2];

    // scanning n variables into array a
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    // copying rows of a(1d array) to b(2d array)
    int l = 0; // variable to traverse 1d array without its own loop
    // traverse 2d array
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
        {
            if (k == 0)
            {
                // if k = 0 that is first col then store 1st col value of 1d array to 2d array
                b[j][k] = a[l++];
            }
            else
            {
                // if other cols come then skip it
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                if (perfcube(b[i][j]))
                {
                    b[i][j + 1] += 5;
                }
                if (divis(b[i][j]))
                {
                    b[i][j + 1] += 4;
                }
                if (prime(b[i][j]))
                {
                    b[i][j + 1] += 3;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            printf("<%d,>", b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return (0);
}
```

I tried approaching the problem like this and ended up with an output like this.  Please help me proceed from here.

```
    Output
    <10,><0,>
    <36,><4,>
    <54,><0,>
    <89,><3,>
    <12,><4,>
    <216,><9,>
    <27,><5,>
```

I am new to programming

I have tried approaching the problem like this and ended up with an output like that.

Please help me proceed from here.

I am not allowed to use pointers or functions like qsort

How do I sort these in that format and print it
[Output of the program that I ended up with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxtcK.png).

The output should match the question.

Comment: Do you know about structures yet?  One way would be to create `struct Value { int number; int weight; };` and sort the array of structures based on the weight values.  Failing that, you probably need an array of values and an array of weights.  You can then sort both arrays with the same swaps based on the comparisons of the weights.

Comment: @GnanaPrakash: I have posted an answer to that one.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting, at its core, centers around the comparison of two items. For example, if A < B, then A should come before B.

For example, we can reorder

```
3 5 2 1 4
```

to

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

We can see it is correct because each adjacent pair maintains a ≤ relationship.

This relationship is a *comparison function*. The one used for your standard sorting looks something like this:

```
bool compare( int a, int b )
{
  return a <= b;
}
```

What your homework is asking you to do is change the comparison function to *not* compare the values directly, but compare *the results of a function* applied to them:

```
bool compare( int a, int b )
{
  return weight_function( a ) <= weight_function( b );
}
```

You must write and implement the weight function, then use it in your sorting algorithm.

(Your algorithm probably has an `if (a <= b)` in it somewhere, which you *could* rewrite as `if (compare( a, b ))`... but you don’t need to do that, just use the weight functions properly.